# Constructing Turing degrees near $\mathcal{O}$

Tags: computability-theory

I'm looking for some examples of constructions for Turing degrees close to, but not above, Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$.  I know of one by Jockusch and Simpson using forcing with hyperarithmetic, uniformly pointed perfect trees, and this construction has the property that it lets you force the triple jump of the degree constructed.  I'd like some other examples of constructions, particularly ones that let you force the double jump but not the triple jump.  Does anyone know of any?

Comment: Sorry for the very late and non-productive comment but I stumbled upon this by browsing through posts and was wondering if you found any relevant answer in the meantime?

Comment: @H.CManu No, I didn't.

Comment: I see, I was hoping otherwise because I find the question very interesting. Can you provide me the reference for the one you know of by Jockush and Soare please?

Comment: @H.CManu It's this one: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484376900231

Comment: Oh it's free too, thank you